# resize navigation bar with image in middle?

Tags: html, css

```css
    nav
    {
     display: table;
     width: 50%;
     background-color: #333;
     padding: 0.50em 0.5em;
     margin: 0.60em auto;
    }
    
    nav ul
    {
     display: table-row;
    }
    
    nav ul li
    {
     display: table-cell;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    a
    {
       text-decoration:none;
       color: #d9d9d9;
    }
    
    a:hover
    {
     color: #e6e6e6;
    }
```

```html
      <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="art.html"> art </a><li>
        <li><a href="download.html"> download </a></li>
        <li><a href="home.html"> <img src="image/symbol.png"></a>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html"> portfolio </a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html"> product </a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
```

The above code is how I am so far designing my website; however, if I add the image in the middle of the bar, the bar widens to fit the image in it!

The answer has been posted, thanks again!

Comment: Could you try setting fixed height and width to the image inside the nav.

Comment: give a fixed height and width for the image.

Comment: I want the following done if possible;

1. move the words portfolio and product to the right so it exact opposite of the words art and download via spacing.

2. looking at the following picture; https://hostr.co/z6vIjIoAbxSo

i want the bar to stay the same height regardless if i put the following in the middle.

https://hostr.co/YuqH2EsQujw9

Comment: use `position` and the use `zindex`

Comment: @Beelzebub i want the bar to stay the same height? same height of what, center logo is bigger in size so you want your nav to be aligned inline along-with it or what.

Comment: check the answer I marked, i just need the picture sticking out from the top not bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.navContain{
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:red;
  padding-top:30px;
}
nav{
   width: 100%;
   max-width:400px;
   background-color: #333;
   padding:0;
   margin:0 auto;
   overflow:visible;
   height:30px;
}
nav ul{
   overflow:visible;
   height:30px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}   
nav ul li{
  text-align: center;
  overflow:visible;
  height:30px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  max-width:80px;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  overflow:visible;
  line-height:30px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}
a:hover{
  color: #e6e6e6;
}
a img{
  width:90%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-30px;
  right:5%;
  left:5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navContain">
<nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="art.html"> art </a></li>
        <li><a href="download.html"> download </a></li>
        <li><a href="home.html"> <img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html"> portfolio </a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html"> product </a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: anyway the image can be sticking out on top and not down?

Comment: or do you want the image to flow out of the navbar? sorry it took so much time, my wifi just disconnected.

Comment: sorry for the delay. actually using table-cell was creating the problem. it never lets it's contents to overflow

Comment: Thank you so much!